# MATLAB pdist function

Tags: matlab, matrix, pdist

I am using the pdist command to find the distance between x and y coordinates stored in a matrix.

```
X = [100 100;
      0  100;
     100  0;
     500 400;
     300 600;];

D = pdist(X,'euclidean')
```

Which returns a 15 element vector. :

```
[0.734979755525412 3.40039811339820 2.93175207511321   1.83879677592575 2.40127440268306 2.75251513299386 2.21488402640753 1.10610649500317 1.81674017301699 0.903207751535635 1.99116952754924 1.05069952386082 1.24122819418333 1.08583377275532 1.38729428638035]
```

Is there a way to associate these distances with the coordinates they were derived from, i.e. store them in a matrix with the general row form:

```
[Length xcoordinate1 ycoordinate1 xcoordinate2 ycoordinate2]
```

Where there is a row for each length found?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your example correct? I got a 10 element vector with *very* different values.

Comment: another function you might find useful is SQUAREFORM http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/stats/squareform.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
%# define X, D
X = [100 100;
      0  100;
     100  0;
     500 400;
     300 600;];

D = pdist(X,'euclidean');

%# find the indices corresponding to each distance
tmp = ones(size(X,1));
tmp = tril(tmp,-1); %# creates a matrix that has 1's below the diagonal

%# get the indices of the 1's
[rowIdx,colIdx ] = find(tmp);

%# create the output
out = [D',X(rowIdx,:),X(colIdx,:)];
```

Answer (score 12):

MATLAB has an inbuilt command called "squareform" that converts a pdist output to an n x n distance matrix http://www.kxcad.net/cae_MATLAB/toolbox/stats/pdist.html

```
%# define X, D
X = [100 100;
      0  100;
      100  0;
     500 400;
     300 600;];

D = squareform(pdist(X,'euclidean'));
```

Comment: Just a comment for python user who met the same problem. In scipy, you can also use `squareform` to tranform the result of `pdist` into a square array.  The functions can be found in `scipy.spatial.distance`.  cf. [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079563/how-does-condensed-distance-matrix-work-pdist)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [NCHOOSEK](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/nchoosek.html) to generate a set of indices into `X` and build your matrix in the following way:

```
>> X = [100 100; 0 100; 100 0; 500 400; 300 600];  %# Your sample data
>> D = pdist(X,'euclidean')'  %'# Euclidean distance, with result transposed

D =

  100.0000    %# Note that I get different results than your example!
  100.0000
  500.0000
  538.5165
  141.4214
  583.0952
  583.0952
  565.6854
  632.4555
  282.8427

>> index = nchoosek(1:size(X,1),2);
>> M = [D X(index(:,1),:) X(index(:,2),:)]    %# [Distance X1 Y1 X2 Y2]

M =

  100.0000  100.0000  100.0000         0  100.0000
  100.0000  100.0000  100.0000  100.0000         0
  500.0000  100.0000  100.0000  500.0000  400.0000
  538.5165  100.0000  100.0000  300.0000  600.0000
  141.4214         0  100.0000  100.0000         0
  583.0952         0  100.0000  500.0000  400.0000
  583.0952         0  100.0000  300.0000  600.0000
  565.6854  100.0000         0  500.0000  400.0000
  632.4555  100.0000         0  300.0000  600.0000
  282.8427  500.0000  400.0000  300.0000  600.0000
```

Note that the function [NCHOOSEK](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/nchoosek.html) will only be a practical solution if the number of columns in `X` is less than around 15.

**edit**: since `pdist` selects pairs of points, the seconds argument to `nchoosek` should simply be `2`. It is independent of the dimensionality of your data. This also makes the note on the preceding line obsolete. (sorry for the edit this way, not enough rep to add a comment, but I really liked this answer and wanted to fix it) -- Paul