# How does condensed distance matrix work? (pdist)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` returns a condensed distance matrix. From [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html):

> Returns a condensed distance matrix Y. For each  and  (where ), the metric dist(u=X[i], v=X[j]) is computed and stored in entry ij.

I thought `ij` meant `i*j`. But I think I might be wrong. Consider

```py
X = array([[1,2], [1,2], [3,4]])
dist_matrix = pdist(X)
```

then the documentation says that `dist(X[0], X[2])` should be `dist_matrix[0*2]`. However, `dist_matrix[0*2]` is 0 -- not 2.8 as it should be.

What's the formula I should use to access the similarity of a two vectors, given `i` and `j`?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can look at it this way:  Suppose `x` is m by n.  The possible pairs of `m` rows, chosen two at a time, is `itertools.combinations(range(m), 2)`, e.g, for `m=3`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(combinations(range(3),2))
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
```

So if `d = pdist(x)`, the `k`th tuple in `combinations(range(m), 2))` gives the indices of the rows of `x` associated with `d[k]`.

Example:

```
>>> x = array([[0,10],[10,10],[20,20]])
>>> pdist(x)
array([ 10.        ,  22.36067977,  14.14213562])
```

The first element is `dist(x[0], x[1])`, the second is `dist(x[0], x[2])` and the third is `dist(x[1], x[2])`.

Or you can view it as the elements in the upper triangular part of the square distance matrix, strung together into a 1D array.

E.g.

```
>>> squareform(pdist(x)) 
array([[  0.   ,  10.   ,  22.361],
       [ 10.   ,   0.   ,  14.142],
       [ 22.361,  14.142,   0.   ]])

>>> y = array([[0,10],[10,10],[20,20],[10,0]])
>>> squareform(pdist(y)) 
array([[  0.   ,  10.   ,  22.361,  14.142],
       [ 10.   ,   0.   ,  14.142,  10.   ],
       [ 22.361,  14.142,   0.   ,  22.361],
       [ 14.142,  10.   ,  22.361,   0.   ]])
>>> pdist(y)
array([ 10.   ,  22.361,  14.142,  14.142,  10.   ,  22.361])
```

Comment: I see, interesting. The squareform is easier to use, it seems. sq_form[i,j] will get me exactly the distance between y[i] and y[j]. However, I think the condensed form is better memory-wise. Perhaps I should read a little bit more on what squareform does. But there isn't a simple formula which converts i,j into a dist position, then?

Comment: Is this actually documented behavior? It makes sense, sure, but nothing in the API makes it seem like it should collate with `combinations(range(m), 2))`, which corresponds to the lower triangle of the distance matrix. Why not the upper?

Comment: Why do you say it corresponds to the lower triangle?  For example, `list(combinations(range(4), 2))` gives `[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]`.  Each tuple in that list has the form (row_index, column_index), so it corresponds to the upper triangle.

Answer (score 54):

## Condensed distance matrix to full distance matrix

A condensed distance matrix as returned by pdist can be converted to a full distance matrix by using `scipy.spatial.distance.squareform`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
>>> points = np.array([[0,1],[1,1],[3,5], [15, 5]])
>>> dist_condensed = pdist(points)
>>> dist_condensed
array([  1.        ,   5.        ,  15.5241747 ,   4.47213595,
        14.56021978,  12.        ])
```

Use `squareform` to convert to full matrix:

```
>>> dist = squareform(dist_condensed)
array([[  0.        ,   1.        ,   5.        ,  15.5241747 ],
       [  1.        ,   0.        ,   4.47213595,  14.56021978],
       [  5.        ,   4.47213595,   0.        ,  12.        ],
       [ 15.5241747 ,  14.56021978,  12.        ,   0.        ]])
```

Distance between point i,j is stored in dist[i, j]:

```
>>> dist[2, 0]
5.0
>>> np.linalg.norm(points[2] - points[0])
5.0
```

## Indices to condensed index

One can convert indices used for accessing the elements of the square matrix to the index in the condensed matrix:

```
def square_to_condensed(i, j, n):
    assert i != j, "no diagonal elements in condensed matrix"
    if i < j:
        i, j = j, i
    return n*j - j*(j+1)//2 + i - 1 - j
```

Example:

```
>>> square_to_condensed(1, 2, len(points))
3
>>> dist_condensed[3]
4.4721359549995796
>>> dist[1,2]
4.4721359549995796
```

## Condensed index to indices

Also the other direction is possible without sqaureform which is better in terms of runtime and memory consumption:

```
import math

def calc_row_idx(k, n):
    return int(math.ceil((1/2.) * (- (-8*k + 4 *n**2 -4*n - 7)**0.5 + 2*n -1) - 1))

def elem_in_i_rows(i, n):
    return i * (n - 1 - i) + (i*(i + 1))//2

def calc_col_idx(k, i, n):
    return int(n - elem_in_i_rows(i + 1, n) + k)

def condensed_to_square(k, n):
    i = calc_row_idx(k, n)
    j = calc_col_idx(k, i, n)
    return i, j
```

Example:

```
>>> condensed_to_square(3, 4)
(1.0, 2.0)
```

## Runtime comparison with squareform

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
>>> points = np.random.random((10**4,3))
>>> %timeit dist_condensed = pdist(points)
1 loops, best of 3: 555 ms per loop
```

Creating the sqaureform turns out to be really slow:

```
>>> dist_condensed = pdist(points)
>>> %timeit dist = squareform(dist_condensed)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.25 s per loop
```

If we are searching two points with maximum distance it is not surprising that searching in full matrix is O(n) while in condensed form only O(n/2):

```
>>> dist = squareform(dist_condensed)
>>> %timeit dist_condensed.argmax()
10 loops, best of 3: 45.2 ms per loop
>>> %timeit dist.argmax()
10 loops, best of 3: 93.3 ms per loop
```

Getting the inideces for the two points takes almost no time in both cases but of course there is some overhead for calculating the condensed index:

```
>>> idx_flat = dist.argmax()
>>> idx_condensed = dist.argmax()
>>> %timeit list(np.unravel_index(idx_flat, dist.shape))
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.28 µs per loop
>>> %timeit condensed_to_square(idx_condensed, len(points))
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.7 µs per loop
```

Comment: I have a distance matrix in square form -- is there a function  to convert to condensed form? (i.e.  does the opposite of `squareform`) ... Functions like [linkage](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html) expect condensed form... **EDIT** The `squareform` function will go both ways ... *Way* cool... ["... **and vice-versa.**"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html) **EDIT 2** I called "square-form" should be "redundant" **EDIT 3** and linkage will work with *both* forms...

Comment: @The Red Pea squareform is its own inverse (i.e. when run on a complete distance matrix, it converts it to squareform)

Comment: How did you figure out `calc_row_idx` and `calc_col_idx`?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai if I recall correctly the idea is to take the formula from `square_to_condensed()` and to solve by i or j by using the quadratic formula. The calculation is a bit cumbersome as far as I remember, but it involves only basic algebra and some reasoning which solution is impossible (because it is negative or complex). Drawing an example triangle matrix with empty diagonal helps a bit.

Comment: In Python 3, "Indices to condensed index" should use integer division `//` instead of floating-point division `/`, so that the output is an integer.

Comment: @mic thanks for pointing that out! I've updated the answer. I have to admit, I was still using Python 2.x in 2016 in my day job.

Answer (score 18):

The vector of the compressed matrix corresponds to the bottom triangular region of the square matrix. To convert for a point in that triangular region, you need to calculate the number of points to the left in the triangle, and the number above in the column.

You can use the following function to convert:

```
q = lambda i,j,n: n*j - j*(j+1)/2 + i - 1 - j
```

Check:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
x = np.random.uniform( size = 100 ).reshape( ( 50, 2 ) )
d = pdist( x )
ds = squareform( d )
for i in xrange( 1, 50 ):
    for j in xrange( i ):
        assert ds[ i, j ] == d[ q( i, j, 50 ) ]
```

Comment: Note that it really is the *bottom* triangular region, which might be strange to some.

Comment: The bottom triangle is the transpose of the upper triangle because the distance matrix is symemtric, i.e. swapping j,i -> i,j gives identical results. Your solution uses the lower triangle interpretation, but there's nothing incorrect about the upper triangle version (which I think is the more common way people think about this)

Comment: I'm trying to move in the opposite direction: given an index into the condensed distance matrix (i.e. the flat vector), how can I get the matrix indexes (i,j) that correspond to that value without coercing it to the square form?

Comment: squareform serialises the distance vector by rows. this means the smaller index is always the first: (0,1),(0,2),(0,3)....

Answer (score 9):

I had the same question. And I found it simpler to use `numpy.triu_indices`:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
N = 10

# Calculate distances
X = np.random.random((N,3))
dist_condensed = pdist(X)

# Get indexes: matrix indices of dist_condensed[i] are [a[i],b[i]]
a,b = np.triu_indices(N,k=1)

# Fill distance matrix
dist_matrix = np.zeros((N,N))
for i in range(len(dist_condensed)):
    dist_matrix[a[i],b[i]] = dist_condensed[i]
    dist_matrix[b[i],a[i]] = dist_condensed[i]

# Compare with squareform output
np.all(dist_matrix == squareform(dist_condensed))
```

Answer (score 6):

This is the **upper triangle** version (**i < j**), which must be interesting to some:

```
condensed_idx = lambda i,j,n: i*n + j - i*(i+1)/2 - i - 1
```

This is very easy to understand:

1. with `i*n + j` you go to the position in the square-formed matrix;
2. with `- i*(i+1)/2` you remove lower triangle (including diagonal) in all lines before i;
3. with `- i` you remove positions in line i before the diagonal;
4. with `- 1` you remove positions in line i on the diagonal.

Check:

```
import scipy
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
condensed_idx = lambda i,j,n: i*n + j - i*(i+1)/2 - i - 1
n = 50
dim = 2
x = scipy.random.uniform(size = n*dim).reshape((n, dim))
d = pdist(x)
ds = squareform(d)
for i in xrange(1, n-1):
    for j in xrange(i+1, n):
        assert ds[i, j] == d[condensed_idx(i, j, n)]
```

Answer (score 5):

If someone is looking for an inverse transformation (i.e. given an element index `idx`, figure out which `(i, j)` element corresponds to it), here is a resonably vectored solution:

```
def actual_indices(idx, n):
    n_row_elems = np.cumsum(np.arange(1, n)[::-1])
    ii = (n_row_elems[:, None] - 1 < idx[None, :]).sum(axis=0)
    shifts = np.concatenate([[0], n_row_elems])
    jj = np.arange(1, n)[ii] + idx - shifts[ii]
    return ii, jj

n = 5
k = 10
idx = np.random.randint(0, n, k)
a = pdist(np.random.rand(n, n))
b = squareform(a)

ii, jj = actual_indices(idx, n)]
assert np.allclose(b[ii, jj, a[idx])
```

I used it to figure out indexes of closest rows in a matrix.

```
m = 3  # how many closest
lowest_dist_idx = np.argpartition(-a, -m)[-m:]
ii, jj = actual_indices(lowest_dist_idx, n)  # rows ii[0] and jj[0] are closest
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to access the element of `pdist` corresponding to the (i,j)-th element of the square distance matrix, the math is as follows:  Assume `i < j` (otherwise flip indices)  if `i == j`, the answer is 0.

```
X = random((N,m))
dist_matrix = pdist(X)
```

Then the (i,j)-th element is dist_matrix[ind] where

```
ind = (N - array(range(1,i+1))).sum()  + (j - 1 - i).
```

Comment: Note that `array(range(1,i+1))).sum() == ((i+1)*i)/2` (google for "Young Gauss").

Comment: If I have an array `array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])` with N = 5, your formula at row i = 3 and column j = 2 `(5 - np.array(range(1,3+1))).sum() + (2 - 1 - 3)` would give me 7, and should give me 5.