# Calculating cosine distance between the rows of matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, trigonometry

I'm trying to calculate cosine distance in python between the rows in matrix and have couple a questions.So I'm creating matrix matr and populating it from the lists, then reshaping it for analysis purposes:

```
s = []

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(b_list)):
        s.append(a[i].count(b_list[j]))

matr = np.array(s) 
d = matr.reshape((22, 254))
```

The output of d gives me smth like:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, ..., 1, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ..., 
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]])
```

Then I want to use scipy.spatial.distance.cosine package to calculate cosine from first row to every other else in the d matrix.
How can I perform that? Should it be some for loop for that? Not too much experience with matrix and array operations.

So how can I use for loop for second argument (d[1],d[2], and so on) in that construction not to launch it every time:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
x=cosine (d[0], d[6])
```

Comment: Doesn't that package have a `pairwise` function or two?

Comment: I'm afraid not- it uses cosine which uses 2 1-D arrays as inputs like this:cosine (u,v), where u,v-1-D arrays.

Comment: Are you using numpy?

Comment: numpy for arrays, scipy-for cosine

Comment: I was thinking of the `pdist` mentioned in one of the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use a simple for loop with `scipy.spatial.distance.cosine`:

```
import scipy.spatial.distance

dists = []
for row in matr:
    dists.append(scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(matr[0,:], row))
```

Answer (score 10):

You said "calculate cosine from first row to every other else in the d matrix" [sic].  If I understand correctly, you can do that with [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html), passing the first row as the first argument and the remaining rows as the second argument:

```
In [31]: from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

In [32]: matr = np.random.randint(0, 3, size=(6, 8))

In [33]: matr
Out[33]: 
array([[1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]])

In [34]: cdist(matr[0:1], matr[1:], metric='cosine')
Out[34]: array([[ 0.65811827,  0.5545646 ,  0.1752139 ,  0.24407105,  0.72499045]])
```

---

If it turns out that you want to compute *all* the pairwise distances in `matr`, you can use [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html).

For example,

```
In [35]: from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

In [36]: pdist(matr, metric='cosine')
Out[36]: 
array([ 0.65811827,  0.5545646 ,  0.1752139 ,  0.24407105,  0.72499045,
        0.36039785,  0.27625314,  0.49748109,  0.41498206,  0.2799177 ,
        0.76429774,  0.37117185,  0.41808563,  0.5765951 ,  0.67661917])
```

Note that the first five values returned by `pdist` are the same values returned above using `cdist`.

For further explanation of the return value of `pdist`, see [How does condensed distance matrix work? (pdist)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079563/how-does-condensed-distance-matrix-work-pdist)

Comment: that answer seems wrong though, doesn't it? I'd expect the distance to be '0' for all 'self' comparisons.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou The result computed by `pdist` doesn't include any of the 'self' comparisons.  See the description in the link I provided at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you might calculate it easily by hand:

```
from numpy import array as a
from numpy.random import random_integers as randi
from numpy.linalg.linalg import norm
from numpy import set_printoptions

M = randi(10, size=a([5,5]));   # create demo matrix

# dot products of rows against themselves
DotProducts = M.dot(M.T);       

# kronecker product of row norms
NormKronecker = a([norm(M, axis=1)]) * a([norm(M, axis=1)]).T; 

CosineSimilarity = DotProducts / NormKronecker
CosineDistance = 1 - CosineSimilarity

set_printoptions(precision=2, suppress=True)
print CosineDistance
```

Output:

```
[[-0.    0.15  0.1   0.11  0.22]
 [ 0.15  0.    0.15  0.13  0.06]
 [ 0.1   0.15  0.    0.15  0.14]
 [ 0.11  0.13  0.15  0.    0.18]
 [ 0.22  0.06  0.14  0.18 -0.  ]]
```

This matrix is e.g. interpreted as "the cosine distance between row 3 against row 2 (or, equally, row 2 against row 3) is 0.15".