# scipy.cluster.hierarchy: labels seems not in the right order, and confused by the value of the vertical axes

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy, linkage, dendrogram

I know that scipy.cluster.hierarchy focused on dealing with the distance matrix. But now I have a similarity matrix... After I plot it by using Dendrogram, something weird just happens.
Here is the code:

```
similarityMatrix = np.array(([1,0.75,0.75,0,0,0,0],
                         [0.75,1,1,0.25,0,0,0],
                         [0.75,1,1,0.25,0,0,0],
                         [0,0.25,0.25,1,0.25,0.25,0],
                         [0,0,0,0.25,1,1,0.75],
                         [0,0,0,0.25,1,1,0.75],
                         [0,0,0,0,0.75,0.75,1]))
```

here is the linkage method

```
Z_sim = sch.linkage(similarityMatrix)
plt.figure(1)
plt.title('similarity')
sch.dendrogram(
    Z_sim,
    labels=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
)
plt.show()
```

But here is the outcome:

[image]

My question is:

1. Why is the label for this dendrogram not right?
2. I am giving a similarity matrix for the linkage method, but I cannot fully understand what the vertical axes means. For example, as the maximum similarity is 1, why is the maximum value in the vertical axes almost 1.6?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: sorry, i do not know why they give me the link to the outcome, rather than just show it in this page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `linkage` expects "distances", not "similarities".  To convert your matrix to something like a distance matrix, you can subtract it from 1:

  ```
  dist = 1 - similarityMatrix
  ```
- `linkage` does not accept a square distance matrix.  It expects the distance data to be in ["condensed" form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079563/how-does-condensed-distance-matrix-work-pdist).  You can get that using `scipy.spatial.distance.squareform`:

  ```
  from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform

  dist = 1 - similarityMatrix
  condensed_dist = squareform(dist)
  Z_sim = sch.linkage(condensed_dist)
  ```

  (When you pass a two-dimensional array with shape (m, n) to `linkage`, it treats the rows as points in n-dimensional space, and computes the distances internally.)

Comment: Thank you very much... by introducing squareform func, I can make the Y axis looks right... This is very useful...