# Dendrogram or Other Plot from Distance Matrix

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, cluster-analysis, dendrogram

I have three matrices to compare. Each of them is 5x6. I originally wanted to use hierarchical clustering to cluster the matrices, such that the most similar matrices are grouped, given a threshold of similarity.

I could not find any such functions in python, so I implemented the distance measure by hand, [(p-norm where p=2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507742/distance-similarity-between-two-matrices). Now I have a 3x3 distance matrix (which I believe is also a similarity matrix in this case).

I am now trying to produce a dendrogram. This is my code, and this is what is wrong. I *want* to produce a graph (a dendrogram if possible) that shows clusters of the matrices that are most similar. Of matrices 0,1,2, 0 and 2 are the same and should be clustered together first, and 1 is different.

The distance matrix looks like this:

```
>   0     1    2 
0   0.0    2.0  3.85e-16
1   2.0    0.0  2.0
2 3.85e-16 2.0  0.0
```

Code:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage
mat = np.array([[0.0, 2.0, 3.8459253727671276e-16], [2.0, 0.0, 2.0], [3.8459253727671276e-16, 2.0, 0.0]])
dist_mat = mat
linkage_matrix = linkage(dist_mat, "single")
dendrogram(linkage_matrix, color_threshold=1, labels=["0", "1", "2"],show_leaf_counts=True)
plt.title=("test")
plt.show()
```

This is the output:
[image]

What is the meaning of the linkage(dist_mat, 'single')? I would have assumed the output graph to look something like this, where the distance is 2.0 between 0 and 1 (for example).
[image]

Are there better ways to represent these data? Is there a function that could take in several matrices instead of points, to compare and form a distance matrix, and then cluster? I am open to other suggestions on how to visualize the differences between these matrices.

Comment: This seems to be correct, it means that first class 0 and 2 are grouped and then both of them grouped with 1. The height is the distance, and since the cluster of (0,2) has distance of about ~3.4 everything is in working order

Comment: @JeD - Thank you. Is there a function that could take in several matrices instead of points, to compare and form a distance matrix, and then cluster?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The first argument of [`linkage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html) should not be the square distance matrix.  It must be the [*condensed* distance matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079563/how-does-condensed-distance-matrix-work-pdist).  In your case, that would be `np.array([2.0, 3.8459253727671276e-16, 2])`.  You can convert from the square distance matrix to the condensed form using [`scipy.spatial.distance.squareform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html)

If you pass a two dimensional array to `linkage` with shape `(m, n)`, it treats it as an array of `m` points in `n`-dimensional space and it computes the distances of those points itself.  That's why you didn't get an error when you passed in the square distance matrix--but you got an incorrect plot.  (This is an undocumented "feature" of `linkage`.)

Also note that because the distance 3.8e-16 is so small, the horizontal line associated with the link between points 0 and 2 might not be visible in the plot--it is on the x axis.

Here's a modified version of your script.  For this example, I've changed that tiny distance to 0.1, so the associated cluster is not obscured by the x axis.

```
import numpy as np

from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


mat = np.array([[0.0, 2.0, 0.1], [2.0, 0.0, 2.0], [0.1, 2.0, 0.0]])
dists = squareform(mat)
linkage_matrix = linkage(dists, "single")
dendrogram(linkage_matrix, labels=["0", "1", "2"])
plt.title("test")
plt.show()
```

Here is the plot created by the script:

[image: dendrogram plot]

Comment: how do i get dendrogram if the distance matrix is asymmetric? any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Warren.. I have a doubt here..if we plot the above diagram like a mirror image will there be ay difference? i.ie draw 0,2 first & then (0,2)->1 both implies same?