# Convert scipy condensed distance matrix to lower matrix read by rows

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a condensed distance matrix from scipy that I need to pass to a C function that requires the matrix be converted to the lower triangle read by rows. For example:

```
0 1 2 3 
  0 4 5 
    0 6
      0
```

The condensed form of this is: `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` but I need to convert it to

```
0
1 0
2 4 0
3 5 6 0
```

The lower triangle read by rows is: `[1,2,4,3,5,6]`.

I was hoping to convert the compact distance matrix to this form without creating a redundant matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick implementation--but it creates the square redundant distance matrix as an intermediate step:

```
In [128]: import numpy as np

In [129]: from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform
```

`c` is the condensed form of the distance matrix:

```
In [130]: c = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

`d` is the redundant square distance matrix:

```
In [131]: d = squareform(c)
```

Here's your condensed lower triangle distances:

```
In [132]: d[np.tril_indices(d.shape[0], -1)]
Out[132]: array([1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6])
```

---

Here's a method that avoids forming the redundant distance matrix.  The function `condensed_index(i, j, n)` takes the row `i` and column `j` of the redundant distance matrix, with `j` > `i`, and returns the corresponding index in the condensed distance array.

```
In [169]: def condensed_index(i, j, n):
     ...:     return n*i - i*(i+1)//2 + j - i - 1
     ...:
```

As above, `c` is the condensed distance array.

```
In [170]: c
Out[170]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

In [171]: n = 4

In [172]: i, j = np.tril_indices(n, -1)
```

Note that the arguments are reversed in the following call:

```
In [173]: indices = condensed_index(j, i, n)
```

`indices` gives the desired permutation of the condensed distance array.

```
In [174]: c[indices]
Out[174]: array([1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6])
```

(Basically the same function as `condensed_index(i, j, n)` was given in several answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079563/how-does-condensed-distance-matrix-work-pdist).)

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to avoid it, because my matrix is quite large (10k - 20k rows), but at least I can use this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I read that question earlier and for some reason my brain didn't put it together.