# Python: Dendogram with Scipy doesn´t work

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

I want to use the dendogram of scipy.
I have the following data:

I have a list with seven different means. For example:

```
Y = [71.407452200146807, 0, 33.700136456196823, 1112.3757110973756, 31.594949722819372, 34.823881975554166, 28.36368420190157]
```

Each mean is calculate for a different user. For example:

```
X = ["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user5", "user6", "user7"]
```

My aim is to display the data described above with the help of a dendorgram.

I tried the following:

```
Y = [71.407452200146807, 0, 33.700136456196823, 1112.3757110973756, 31.594949722819372, 34.823881975554166, 28.36368420190157]
X = ["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user5", "user6", "user7"]

# Attempt with matrix
#X = np.concatenate((X, Y),)
#Z = linkage(X)

Z = linkage(Y)
# Plot the dendogram with the results above
dendrogram(Z, leaf_rotation=45., leaf_font_size=12. , show_contracted=True)
plt.style.use("seaborn-whitegrid")
plt.title("Dendogram to find clusters")
plt.ylabel("Distance")
plt.show()
```

But it says:

> ValueError: Length n of condensed distance matrix 'y' must be a binomial coefficient, i.e.there must be a k such that (k \choose 2)=n)!

I already tried to convert my data into a matrix. With:

```
# Attempt with matrix
#X = np.concatenate((X, Y),)
#Z = linkage(X)
```

But that doesn´t work too!

Are there any suggestions?

Thanks :-)

Comment: what I have understood by reading the documentation so far is `y must be a (n|2) sized vector`. I tried your code and if `len(Y)` is 15 it works. Trying to figure out why it won't work for anything less than that.

Comment: Sounds weird. But this is actually a use case, isn't it? It should be possible to build clusters of users which have the "same" mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are using 7 observations in `Y` len(Y) = 7.

But as per documentation of [Linkage](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage), the number of observations `len(Y)` should be such that.

```
{n \choose 2} = len(Y)
```

which means

```
1/2 * (n -1) * n = len(Y)
```

so length of Y should be such that n is a valid integer.

Comment: Your are right. I extended my Y and it works. Unfortunately, the dendogram looks weird. There are only single clusters. What is the right way to extend my Y? I tried to extend it with the same values again.. like `Y.extend(Y)`

Comment: Instead of calculating the mean I used the original values. Thus, my Y is bigger. This worked for me :-) Thanks a lot

Comment: The meaning of the first argument of `linkage` depends on the number of dimensions of the argument.  When it is one-dimensional, the values are interpreted as the pairwise distances between the points, stored in the condensed arrangement, *not* as the points (i.e. observations) themselves.  It is not correct to say that the number of *observations* should be `{n \choose 2}`.

Answer (score 11):

The first argument of [`linkage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html) is either an n x m array, representing n points in m-dimensional space, or a one-dimensional array containing the [condensed distance matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079563/how-does-condensed-distance-matrix-work-pdist).  These are two very different meanings!  The first is the raw data, i.e. the *observations*.  The second format assumes that you have already computed all the distances between your observations, and you are providing these distances to `linkage`, not the original points.

It looks like you want the first case (raw data), with m = 1.  So you must reshape the input to have shape (n, 1).

Replace this:

```
Z = linkage(Y)
```

with:

```
Z = linkage(np.reshape(Y, (len(Y), 1)))
```

Comment: It should be the answer because we don't have to modify the length of our data