# Convert distance pairs to distance matrix to use in hierarchical clustering

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to convert a dictionary to a distance matrix that I can then use as an input to hierarchical clustering: I have as an input:

- key: tuple of length 2 with the objects for which I have the distance
- value: the actual distance value

  ```
  for k,v in obj_distances.items():
  print(k,v)
  ```

and the result is :

```
('obj1', 'obj2') 2.0 
('obj3', 'obj4') 1.58
('obj1','obj3') 1.95
('obj2', 'obj3') 1.80
```

My question is how can I convert this into a distance matrix that I can later user for clustering in scipy?

Comment: You can first create a matrix of zeros and then use `int(a[-1])` as the indices of your matrices where `a` is `'obj1'`, `'obj2'` etc. and store the distance values in that array

Comment: Is your set of distances complete?  That is, does the distance dictionary contain a distance for each possible pair?  For example, the data that you show doesn't include distances for `('obj1', 'obj4')` or `('obj2', 'obj4')`.  You'll  need these values to do clustering.

Comment: Hi @WarrenWeckesser, yes it is, I just omitted it to save space, but yes I have all pairwise distances, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you will use scipy for clustering, so I assume that means you will use the function [`scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html).  `linkage` accepts the distance data in "condensed" form, so you don't have to create the full symmetric distance matrix. (See, e.g., [How does condensed distance matrix work? (pdist)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079563/how-does-condensed-distance-matrix-work-pdist), for a discussion on the condensed form.)

So all you have to do is get `obj_distances.values()` into a known order and pass that to `linkage`.  That's what is done in the following snippet:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, dendrogram

obj_distances = {
    ('obj2', 'obj3'): 1.8,
    ('obj3', 'obj1'): 1.95,
    ('obj1', 'obj4'): 2.5,
    ('obj1', 'obj2'): 2.0,
    ('obj4', 'obj2'): 2.1,
    ('obj3', 'obj4'): 1.58,
}

# Put each key pair in a canonical order, so we know that if (a, b) is a key,
# then a < b.  If this is already true, then the next three lines can be
# replaced with
#     sorted_keys, distances = zip(*sorted(obj_distances.items()))
# Note: we assume there are no keys where the two objects are the same.
keys = [sorted(k) for k in obj_distances.keys()]
values = obj_distances.values()
sorted_keys, distances = zip(*sorted(zip(keys, values)))

# linkage accepts the "condensed" format of the distances.
Z = linkage(distances)

# Optional: create a sorted list of the objects.
labels = sorted(set([key[0] for key in sorted_keys] + [sorted_keys[-1][-1]]))

dendrogram(Z, labels=labels)
```

The dendrogram:

[image: dendrogram]

Comment: Thanks @WarrenWeckesser exactly what I was looking to do, appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

Use pandas and unstack the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {('obj1', 'obj2'): 2.0 ,
('obj3', 'obj4'): 1.58,
('obj1','obj3'): 1.95,
('obj2', 'obj3'): 1.80,}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index.tolist())
dist_matrix = df.unstack().values
```

yeilds

```
In [15]: dist_matrix
Out[15]:

array([[2.  , 1.95,  nan],
       [ nan, 1.8 ,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan, 1.58]])
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be slower than the other answer posted, but will ensure that values both above and below the middle diagonal are included, if that's important to you:

```
import pandas as pd

unique_ids = sorted(set([x for y in obj_distance.keys() for x in y]))
df = pd.DataFrame(index=unique_ids, columns=unique_ids)

for k, v in obj_distance.items():
    df.loc[k[0], k[1]] = v
    df.loc[k[1], k[0]] = v
```

Results:

```
      obj1 obj2  obj3  obj4
obj1   NaN    2  1.95   NaN
obj2     2  NaN   1.8   NaN
obj3  1.95  1.8   NaN  1.58
obj4   NaN  NaN  1.58   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @thesilkworm