# scipy linkage with a given distance matrix

Tags: scipy, hierarchical-clustering, linkage

I have a very large sparse matrix (few million rows, 500 columns).
I have already cumputed a distance matrix of 5000X5000.
I need to use `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage` to get the clustering according to this matrix.
I know that `linkage` accepts a custom function, but computing this distance matrix again is very time consuming.
How can I tell scipy to use the distances by the matrix?
I tried

```
dist = my_dist(X) # numpy array ndim = 2
linkage(X, metric=lambda x: dist[x,y])
```

but the `x,y` passed are the values and not the indexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the distance matrix to [`linkage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html) if you represent it as a ["condensed" distance matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079563/how-does-condensed-distance-matrix-work-pdist).  You can use [`scipy.spatial.squareform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html) to convert `dist` to the condensed representation.

Something like this:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform

dist = my_dist(X)
condensed_dist = squareform(dist)
linkresult = linkage(condensed_dist)
```