# Dendrogram with plotly - how to set a custom linkage method for hierarchical clustering

Tags: python, plotly, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I am new to plotly and need to draw a dendrogram with group average linkage.

I am aware that there is a `distfun` parameter in `create_dendrogram()`, but I have no idea what to pass to that argument to get **Group Average Linkage**. The `distfun` argument apparently have to be callable. What function should I pass to it?

As a sidenote, I have a sample pairwise distance matrix 

`0
13 0
2 14 0
17 1 18 0`

which, when I passed to the `create_dendrogram()` method, seems to produce an incorrect result. What am I doing wrong here?

code:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

import numpy as np

X = np.matrix([[0,0,0,0],[13,0,0,0],[2,14,0,0],[17,1,18,0]])

names = list("0123")
fig = ff.create_dendrogram(X, orientation='left', labels=names)
fig.update_layout(width=800, height=800)
fig.show()
```

Code literally copied from the plotly website bc idk wth I'm supposed to do.
This website: https://plotly.com/python/v3/dendrogram/

Comment: Share the link you got this code from?

Answer (score 1):

You can choose a linkage method using [`scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage)
via `linkagefun` argument in `create_dendrogram()` function.

For example, to use [UPGMA (Unweighted Pair Group Method with Arithmetic mean) algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPGMA):

```py
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch
import numpy as np

X = np.matrix([[0,0,0,0],[13,0,0,0],[2,14,0,0],[17,1,18,0]])

names = "0123"
fig = ff.create_dendrogram(X,
                           orientation='left',
                           labels=names,
                           linkagefun=lambda x: sch.linkage(x, "average"),)
fig.update_layout(width=800, height=800)
fig.show()
```

Please, note that `X` has to be a matrix of data samples.

Comment: There is no error indeed. It depends on the method you specify. To give you an example, I used `average`. You can see other linkage methods [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html) and the code [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.4.1/scipy/cluster/hierarchy.py#L833-L1077).

Comment: but it is supposed to group lower distance values first. "average" is the method I need but the grouping is wrong. Since (1,3) has distance 1, It should group 1,3 together but when executed it grouped (0,1) together.

Comment: Ok, I see. `X` has to be a matrix of data samples. NOT a distance matrix.

Comment: Than how do I convert a NxN pairwise distance matrix to a "1d condensed distance matrix" that linkage needs? scipy.spatial.distance.pdist doesn't seem to do the trick. (it requires 2x2 matrix)

Comment: I used `scipy.spatial.distance.squareform` to (supposedly) convert the pairwise matrix to condensed matrix, but when I ran the code I got `in get_dendrogram_traces d=distfun(X) in pdist raise ValueError: A 2-dimentional array must be passed.` How do I fix this?

Comment: You have to simply use your dataset. No conversion. Just use for `X` a matrix of data samples. Rows are samples, columns are features.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210995/discussion-between-sentence-and-user13226847).

Comment: But is there a way to get the distance matrix that plolty dendrogram is based on??

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old but, for anyone else with similar issues, I think the `distfun` param simply specifies how you want to convert your data matrix to a condensed distance matrix - you define the function yourself.

For example, after a bit of head banging I cobbled together `data_to_dist` to convert a data matrix to a Jaccard distance matrix, then condense it.  You should be aware that plotly's dendrogram implementation does not check whether your matrix is condensed so your `distfun` needs to ensure this occurs.  Maybe this is wrong, but it looks like `distfun` should only take one positional param (the data matrix) and return one object (the condensed distance matrix):

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import jaccard, squareform

def jaccard_dissimilarity(feature_list1, feature_list2, filler_val): #binary
    all_features = set([i for i in feature_list1 if i != filler_val])#filler val can be used to even up ragged lists and ignore certain dtypes ie prots not in a module
    all_features.update(set([i for i in feature_list2 if i != filler_val]))#works for both numpy arrays and lists
    counts_1 = [1 if feature in feature_list1 else 0 for feature in all_features]
    counts_2 = [1 if feature in feature_list2 else 0 for feature in all_features]
    return jaccard(counts_1, counts_2)

def data_to_dist_matrix(mn_data, filler_val = 0):
    #notes:
        #the original plotly example uses pdist to find manhatten distance for clustering.  
        #pdist 'Returns a condensed distance matrix Y' - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.
        #a condensed distance matrix is required for input into scipy linkage for clustering.  
        #plotly dendrogram function does not do this conversion to the output of a given distfun call - https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/cfad7862594b35965c0e000813bd7805e8494a5b/packages/python/plotly/plotly/figure_factory/_dendrogram.py#L340
        #therefore you should convert distance matrix to condensed form yourself as below with squareform
    distance_matrix = np.array([[jaccard_dissimilarity(a,b, filler_val) for b in mn_data] for a in mn_data])
    return squareform(distance_matrix)



# toy data to visually check clustering looks sensible
data_array = np.array([[1, 2, 3,0], 
                       [2, 3, 10, 0], 
                       [4, 5, 6, 0],
                       [5, 6, 7, 0],
                       [7, 8, 1, 0],
                       [1,2,8,7],
                       [1,2,3,8],
                       [1,2,3,4]])

y_labels = [f'MODULE_{i}' for i in range(8)]

#this is the distance matrix and condensed distance matrix made by data_to_dist_matrix and is only included so I can check what it's doing
dist_matrix = np.array([[jaccard_dissimilarity(a,b, 0) for b in data_array] for a in data_array])
condensed_dist_matrix = data_to_dist_matrix(data_array, 0)

# Create Side Dendrogram
fig = ff.create_dendrogram(data_array, 
                           orientation='right', 
                           labels = y_labels,
                           distfun = data_to_dist_matrix)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a bit confused regarding condensed/non-condensed distance matrix. If I have a distance matrix to begin with (and not the data themselves), can I just pass `distfun=None`? Will this create the dendrograms based on the distances in the original matrix?

Comment: Perhaps define a distfun with input distance matrix X and output condensed distance matrix sX (or a distfun that returns the input if you have a squareform distance matrix to start with).  I'm hazy about what the condensed distance matrix is, but these links might help - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079563/how-does-condensed-distance-matrix-work-pdist.  IIRC its removing the duplicate values found in every distance matrix (as they are symmetrical across the diagonal), but could be wrong.