# Minimum distance of a dataset

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, distance

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons

X, y = make_moons()
cdist(X,X).min(axis=1)
```

gave me

```
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

This is not what I would like. I would like the minimum distance between all the points in `X` where `i` is not equal to `j`. Of course, if `i=j`, then I would get `0`. How can I do that using `cdist`?

Comment: You basically want to ignore the diagonal of the distance matrix, right? This might not be the most elegant solution, but by adding `inf` (or any other sufficiently large number) to the diagonal, `.min(axis=1)` should work. `(cdist(X, X) + np.diag([np.inf]*len(X))).min(axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cdist` is an overkill to calculate pairwise distances for an array. For an array the upper triangle is minimal meaningful representation of all possible distances not including 0 distances to itself. The way to do it is using [`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html):

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons

X, y = make_moons()
# desired output
pdist(X).min()
```

It returns an upper triange ndarray which is:

> Y: ndarray
> Returns a condensed distance matrix Y. For each i and j (where i<j<m),where m is the number of original observations. The metric dist(u=X[i], v=X[j]) is computed and stored in entry ij.

You may read more about condensed matrix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079563/how-does-condensed-distance-matrix-work-pdist)

Time comparison:

```
%timeit pdist(X)
73 µs ± 825 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit cdist(X,X)
112 µs ± 315 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```