# Clustering data using scipy and a distance matriz in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, matrix, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

I am working in Python. I am using a binary dataframe in which I have a ser of values of 0 and 1 for diferent users at diferent times.

I can perform hierarchical clustering directly from the dataframe as

```
    metodo='average'
    clusters = linkage(user_df, method=metodo,metric='hamming')
    
    # Create a dendrogram
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
    dendrogram(clusters, labels=user_df.index, leaf_rotation=90)
    plt.title('Hierarchical Clustering Dendrogram')
    plt.xlabel('User')
    plt.ylabel('Distance')
# Save the figure
plt.savefig(f'dendrogram_{metodo}_entero.png')
plt.show()
```

However, I want to separate the calculation of the distance matrix and the clustering. To do that, I have calculated the distance matrix and I have sent it as an argument to the clustering.

```
dist_matrix = pdist(user_df.values, metric='hamming')

# Convert the distance matrix to a square form
dist_matrix_square = squareform(dist_matrix)

# Create a DataFrame from the distance matrix
dist_df = pd.DataFrame(dist_matrix_square, index=user_df.index, columns=user_df.index)

clusters = linkage(dist_df, method=metodo)
```

Unfortunately, the results that I obtain are different with both methodologies. As far as I know, the first code is the correct one.

So I don't know if I can calculate the distance matrix and then use it somehow as an argument for clustering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) returns a numpy array that is the [*condensed* distance matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079563/how-does-condensed-distance-matrix-work-pdist).  You can pass this form of the distance matrix directly to [`linkage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html).  Don't convert it to a Pandas DataFrame.

So your code could be as simple as:

```
dist_matrix = pdist(user_df.values, metric='hamming')
clusters = linkage(dist_matrix, method=metodo)
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this means that If I were to use `clusters = linkage(dist_matrix, method=metodo)` and `    clusters = linkage(user_df, method=metodo,metric='hamming')` I would get the same results?

Comment: That is true when the inputs are numpy arrays.  I don't know if there are any edge cases where passing a DataFrame instead of a numpy array to `linkage` could cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple clustering algorithms, it is normal that different algorithms give different results. You can checkout [scikit-learn clustering documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) to have an overview.

As for you question, here are three examples (that I have not tested), where `distance_matrix` is the distance matrix you computed:

## Agglomerative Hierarchical Clustering (SciPy):

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, dendrogram, fcluster

# Create a linkage matrix from the distance matrix
linkage_matrix = linkage(distance_matrix, method='ward')

# Obtain cluster assignments
clusters = fcluster(linkage_matrix, t=threshold, criterion='distance')
```

## K-Means Clustering (scikit-learn):

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

# Specify the number of clusters (n_clusters)
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters, random_state=seed)

# Fit the model to the distance matrix
kmeans.fit(distance_matrix)

# Obtain cluster assignments
clusters = kmeans.labels_
```

## DBSCAN (scikit-learn):

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

# Specify epsilon (eps) and minimum samples (min_samples)
dbscan = DBSCAN(eps=epsilon, min_samples=min_samples, metric='precomputed')

# Fit the model to the distance matrix
dbscan.fit(distance_matrix)

# Obtain cluster assignments (Note: -1 indicates noise/outliers)
clusters = dbscan.labels_
```

Edit:

According to [scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html), the array can be:

- `A condensed distance matrix. A condensed distance matrix is a flat array containing the upper triangular of the distance matrix. This is the form that pdist returns.`
- `Alternatively, a collection of observation vectors in dimensions may be passed as an m by n array.`

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. However, that is not what I am looking for. My question is as follows: Can I use the distance matrix as an argument in `linkage(XXX, method=metodo,metric='hamming')` or I have to use the original data instead.